# About Arrays in Arduino

Tags: array

I have a question about arrays in Arduino. Sorry for my bad English.
I want to put numbers in an array, and I think the code below works properly.

However, it doesn't work and corrupted numbers show up in the Serial monitor. Even `delay(1000)` doesn't work.

If I change `ND_MAC[i]=128;` to "ND_MAC[i]=126;", it works properly. So I'm wondering if this array is char type, but I designate int to array.
How to solve it?

```
int ND_MAC[7];
char i=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    ND_MAC[i]=128;
    Serial.print(ND_MAC[i],HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: First error is iterating outside the array. ND_MAC has 7 elements (0..6).

Answer (score 2):

For an array of size 7, the indexes start from `0` (`ND_MAC[0]`) and end at `6` (`ND_MAC[6]`) as @MikaelPatel commented.

So the solution to your issue would be changing the condition in for loop to

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) //Changed 8 in your code to 7
```

Here, the loop iterates from i = 0 to 1 < 7 (i.e., till 6)
and it should work. :)

Comment: Oh,I had a terrible mistake...

Comment: Oh,I had a terrible mistake... I followed your help, and then it worked properly. thank you very much!

Comment: @kishida you're welcome....